# Titanium: correctly clean up a controller associated with a non-window view

Tags: view, controller, titanium, titanium-alloy

I have an Alloy app structured with a one window divided in two views: a sidebar menu view on the left and a main view on the right.
Each time the user click on a different menu-item in the sidebar I remove all children attached to the main view and load the view/controller related to that menu-item and attach it to the main view. My question: is this sufficient? If the removed view had event listeners attached to elements inside it, are they clean up too or not?
Have I to keep a reference to each controller I have instantiated and call controller.destroy() and controller.off() before I load the new view/controller or is not necessary?

I am asking because with views without window is not possible to attach a cleanup function to the "onclose" event because the UI.View elements can't be "closed" (only windows).

So which is the correct way to handle this situation in Titanium?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The event listeners may keep a reference especially you add them with Ti.APP.addEventListeners.

So, you should remove event listeners manually when you remove all children view.

Comment: But if i only attach event listeners to the inner elements of the view that i am removing, they will survive or not? Thanks for your help

Comment: They will not survive if not bind to collection or model. You could test it with your codes like this: 
add Ti.App.info("some words") in your event listener, close view and reopen it, see how many "some words" shows, if "some words" show twice, it means the event listener in the view you closed is still there.